# How to optimize if statement in python from a parsing script

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have a part of my code I want to optimize. 
I use `if` statement to skip the analyze if the values are not the one I want.
Just to help the comprehension, in my data, R1 is between range(6,15); mis in range(0,1); spacer in range (0,10).

My code is working, but it would be better if it will run faster according to the amount of data I have.

````py
R1 = len(hit_splitted_line1[1])
hit = re.sub(r"\s+", "", lines[i+1])
hit_nb = len(hit)
spacer = pos2_spacer - pos1_spacer - 1

mis = R1 - hit_nb
if (R1 == 6 and mis ==1):
    pass
elif (R1 == 6 and mis == 0 and spacer in range(0,4)) :
    pass
elif (R1 == 7 and mis == 0 and spacer in range(0,2)) :
    pass
elif (R1 == 7 and mis == 1 and spacer in range(0,4)) :
    pass
else :
    if (R1 == 8 and spacer in range(0,1)):
        goodAln = re.search('^\s*\|\|\|\|\|\|', lines[i+1])
        if (not goodAln):
            pass
        else :
            name_list=[str(chr),str(pos_start),str(pos_end)]
            name = '_'.join(name_list)
            ID = "ID="+name+";spacer="+str(spacer)+";repeat="+str(R1)+";mismatch="+str(mis)
            print (chr,"pal2gff","IR",pos_start,pos_end,".","+",".",str(ID),sep='\t')
    else :
        name_list=[str(chr),str(pos_start),str(pos_end)]
        name = '_'.join(name_list)
        ID = "ID="+name+";spacer="+str(spacer)+";repeat="+str(R1)+";mismatch="+str(mis)
        print (chr,"pal2gff","IR",pos_start,pos_end,".","+",".",str(ID),sep='\t')
```
````

Comment: 1) Change your title properly to reflect the purpose of the program 2) Add more context if you asking for performance optimization: what is `lines` and what's its contents? what are `pos_start`, `pos_end` ???

Comment: Hey Leelouh, could you maybe include a sample of your data :) Also, as Roman stated, we'd need to see the variable declarations in order to help you out with a review.

Answer (score 2):

### [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Conventions

- **Do not** use parentheses to cover the `if` statements.
- **Do not** leave a whitespace before the `:` in the `if else` statements.
- **Use** whitespace around operators and commas. `some1,some2` should be `some1, some2`

### General

- Use [formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)
- Use [chained comparisons](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/) instead of `range(x, y)`

Here's what the code might look like in the end:

```
R1 = len(hit_splitted_line1[1])
hit = re.sub(r"\s+", "", lines[i + 1])
hit_nb = len(hit)

spacer = pos2_spacer - pos1_spacer - 1

mis = R1 - hit_nb

if R1 == 6 and mis == 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 6 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 1 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass

else:
    if R1 == 8 and spacer in range(0, 1):
        goodAln = re.search('^\s*\|\|\|\|\|\|', lines[i + 1])

        if not goodAln:
            pass

        else:
            name_list = [str(chr), str(pos_start), str(pos_end)]
            name = '_'.join(name_list)
            ID = f"ID={name};spacer={spacer};repeat={R1};mismatch={mis}"
            print(chr, "pal2gff", "IR", pos_start, pos_end, ".", "+", ".", str(ID), sep='\t')

    else:
        name_list = [str(chr), str(pos_start), str(pos_end)]
        name = '_'.join(name_list)
        ID = f"ID={name};spacer={spacer};repeat={R1};mismatch={mis}"
        print(chr, "pal2gff", "IR", pos_start, pos_end, ".", "+", ".", str(ID), sep='\t')
```

Note:

```
if R1 == 6 and mis == 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 6 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 1 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass
```

You can replace these statements with an if statement, but I did not replace them as the code might still be in development.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements can be optimized from:

```
if R1 == 6 and mis == 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 6 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 1 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass
```

to

```
if R1 == 6:
    if miss == 1:
        pass
    elif 0 <= spacer <= 3:
        pass

elif R1 == 7:
    if miss == 1 and  0 <= spacer <= 3:
        pass
    elif miss == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 1:
        pass
```

You will generate less python internal instructions (opcodes)

Answer (score 1):

Nesting `if` statements isn't considered as clean code. I advise you'd use `bouncer` design pattern. Check your constraints first. If they're are not satisfied, just return.

Answer (score 0):

On what is slow. Not the if-chain.

`ID=...` is very slow, maybe you can pass the terms to `print` individually.

The regular expression usage is slow too. Precompiling regex outside the looping is faster.

The if-chain can be reduced, but to some extent the compiler should be able to do it better. As the code can become a difficult and-or chaos.

Doing it yourself, I would transform

```
if R1 == 6 and mis == 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 6 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 0 and 0 <= spacer <= 1:
    pass

elif R1 == 7 and mis == 1 and 0 <= spacer <= 3:
    pass
```

first *suboptimally* into:

```
r16 = R1 == 6
r17 = R1 == 7
mis0 = mis == 0
mis1 = mis == 1
spg0 = 0 <= spacer
spl1 = spacer <= 1
spl3 = spacer <= 3
```

Receiving the or'ed conditions:

```
r16 and mis1
r16 and mis0 and spg0 and spg3
r17 and mis0 and spg0 and spg1
r17 and mis1 and spg0 and spg3
```

transformed into

```
(r16 and (mis1 
          or (mis0 and spg0 and spg3)
          )
)
or
(r17 and ((mis0 and spg0 and spg1)
          or (mis1 and spg0 and spg3)
         )
)
```

transformed into

```
(r16 and (mis1 
          or (mis0 and spg0 and spg3)
          )
)
or
(r17 and spg0 and ((mis0 and spg1)
          or (mis1 and spg3)
         )
)
```

transformed into

```
(r16 and (mis1 
          or (mis0 and spg0 and spg3)
          )
)
or
(r17 and spg0 and ((mis0 and spg1)
          or (mis1 and spg3)
         )
)
```

These 7 boolean variables would lean themselves using a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)
to the most compact boolean expression.

As said the gain/effort ratio is little.

I would just exploit the exclusive conditions to make a simple nested if.